# SPARK Combining Neighbouring Records in a text file

Tags: apache-spark

very new to SPARK.

I need to read a very large input dataset, but I fear the format of the input files would not be amenable to read on SPARK. Format is as follows:

```
RECORD,record1identifier
SUBRECORD,value1
SUBRECORD2,value2
RECORD,record2identifier
RECORD,record3identifier
SUBRECORD,value3
SUBRECORD,value4
SUBRECORD,value5
...
```

Ideally what I would like to do is pull the lines of the file into a SPARK RDD, and then transform it into an RDD that only has one item per record (with the subrecords becoming part of their associated record item).

So if the example above was read in, I'd want to wind up with an RDD containing 3 objects: [record1,record2,record3]. Each object would contain the data from their RECORD and any associated SUBRECORD entries.

The unfortunate bit is that the only thing in this data that links subrecords to records is their position in the file, underneath their record. That means the problem is sequentially dependent and might not lend itself to SPARK.

Is there a sensible way to do this using SPARK (and if so, what could that be, what transform could be used to collapse the subrecords into their associated record)? Or is this the sort of problem one needs to do off spark?

Comment: of course you can using the position. To avoid the possible missing connections you can work with one partition to create the RDD. If you need the parallelism try to create a partitioner that includes all RECORD and SUBRECORDS in the same partition.

Comment: Thanks @EmiCareOfCell44 how would I collapse the subrecords into their respective record field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a somewhat hackish way to identify the sequence of records and sub-records. This method assumes that each new "record" is identifiable in some way.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
("RECORD","record1identifier"),
("SUBRECORD","value1"),
("SUBRECORD2","value2"),
("RECORD","record2identifier"),
("RECORD","record3identifier"),
("SUBRECORD","value3"),
("SUBRECORD","value4"),
("SUBRECORD","value5")
).toDS().rdd.zipWithIndex.map(r => (r._1._1, r._1._2, r._2)).toDF("record", "value", "id")

val win = Window.orderBy("id")

val recids = df.withColumn("newrec", ($"record" === "RECORD").cast(LongType))
  .withColumn("recid", sum($"newrec").over(win))
  .select($"recid", $"record", $"value")

val recs = recids.where($"record"==="RECORD").select($"recid", $"value".as("recname"))
val subrecs = recids.where($"record" =!= "RECORD").select($"recid", $"value".as("attr"))

recs.join(subrecs, Seq("recid"), "left").groupBy("recname").agg(collect_list("attr").as("attrs")).show()
```

This snippet will first `zipWithIndex` to identify each row, in order, then add a boolean column that is true every time a "record" is identified, and false otherwise. We then cast that boolean to a long, and then can do a running sum, which has the neat side-effect of essentially labeling every record and it's sub-records with a common identifier.

In this particular case, we then split to get the record identifiers, re-join only the sub-records, group by the record ids, and collect the sub-record values to a list.

The above snippet results in this:

```
+-----------------+--------------------+
|          recname|               attrs|
+-----------------+--------------------+
|record1identifier|    [value1, value2]|
|record2identifier|                  []|
|record3identifier|[value3, value4, ...|
+-----------------+--------------------+
```