# How to populate last not null data into column?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

My input DataFrame is looks like below

```
+-------+
|Column1|
+-------+
|FILE_1 |
|11     |
|12     |
|212    |
|FILE_2 |
|1213   |
|13312  |
|4124   |
+-------+
```

In input `DataFrame` FILE_* is the file name and data below FILE_ are its contents.

For example, FILE_1 has 11,12,212 contents.

I want to add new column into existing Input DataFrame which give me this relation of File Name and its contents like below:

```
+-------+-------+
|Column1|Column2|
+-------+-------+
|FILE_1 |FILE_1 |
|11     |FILE_1 |
|12     |FILE_1 |
|212    |FILE_1 |
|FILE_2 |FILE_2 |
|1213   |FILE_2 |
|13312  |FILE_2 |
|4124   |FILE_2 |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: I answered a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58310213/2639647. With some slight modifcations, you can achieve the dataframe you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach to do that:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{last, when}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

    val df = Seq("FILE_1","11","12","212","FILE_2","1213","3312","4124").toDF("column1")
    val w = Window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
    val df2 = df.withColumn("tmp", when($"column1".startsWith("FILE_"), $"column1").otherwise(null))
      .withColumn("column2", last($"tmp", true).over(w)).drop("tmp")
```

[The result looks something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kfl3.png)

Get more info on Spark Window through [this great Databricks post.](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html)